# Script to minimize MySQL InnoDB Primary Keys

Tags: mysql, innodb

I can't work out what to google to find what I'm after - I have a large database which has been imported from many others and has huge gaps in it's primary keys.

The database is InnoDB, and all foreign keys are set properly (well... I hope, anyway).

Is anyone aware of a script which would take the primary keys and minimize them, filling in all of the gaps and updating the FK entries as well?

(e.g. PK 44, 77, 88 becomes 1, 2, 3)

Thanks!

Comment: "and has huge gaps in it's primary keys" --- so what? What is the **real** issue?

Comment: Insert a new auto_increment column and set it as primary key. Insert a new foreign key column to child table and update the new primary keys by their old key values.

Comment: @ zerkms - I have some tables with IDs of 100000 or more when there are only 200 records in the data. True, it's not a huge issue, but it's annoying.

Comment: @daemonl: "True, it's not a huge issue, but it's annoying" --- it's not an issue at all. Neither tiny or huge. Don't rely on PK value ever. So even if it is 99999999 - just use it and don't care

Comment: @Jonas T - I'll call that 'Plan B' - I was hoping that process had been automated by someone in the past - there are quite a few tables, and I know it's theoretically possible for a script to pick up on the relationships and do it without much input from me.

Comment: "I was hoping that process had been automated by someone" --- it's not automated because it makes no sense ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - It's not an issue as far as SQL cares, or scripts, but we still do some manual updates and look-ups for data, and the PK ends up in some of our URLs. It would be 'nice' to clean them up, is all. Is there a reason it shouldn't be done, other than not needing to be done?

Comment: @daemonl: "Is there a reason it shouldn't be done" --- is there a reason it should be done? "and the PK ends up in some of our URLs" -- have you seen facebook or twitter urls?

Comment: And could you imagine them if they weren't sequential (or at least with an offset)? Anyway, facebook doesn't have people calling them saying 'invoice 122156634532 isn't working' - and I COULD add a friendly index, but they aren't my tables :-)

Comment: @daemonl: if you need to have good names - add varchar column and give names that make sense :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with something similar to – Jonas T
"insert a new auto_increment column and set it as primary key. Insert a new foreign key column to child table and update the new primary keys by their old key values. "

In the foreign key definition you have ON DELETE, ON UPDATE. 
If you set ON UPDATE to CASCADE ("ON UPDATE CASCADE") an UPDATE on the primary key will 'cascade' to an UPDATE on the Foreign Key.

My keys are all UNSIGNED int(11), you'll have to use yours, and i used x so that only the table name needs to be changed to run on each table

CV is a working table, Organisation is the table I'm 'minimizing'

```
DROP TABLE cv;
CREATE TABLE cv (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  cv int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO cv (cv)
  SELECT id FROM Organisation ORDER BY id;

UPDATE Organisation x
  LEFT JOIN cv ON cv.cv = x.id
  SET x.id = cv.id;
```